# How to run a service on a specific port without binding with the IP

Tags: python, linux, tcp, port, netcat

I want to run a test listener on a specific port to check whether the port is open or not, however whenever i start a listener using netcat, it binds with `0.0.0.0:8080` Ip address. 
I want to start a wild card service like `:::8080` `using netcat -l -p 8080` or any known way.

Script i'm using to check the availability

```
with closing(socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)) as sock:
if sock.connect_ex((ip,port)) == 0:
        print "Port is open";
else:
        print "Port is close";
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to check with a listener, if a port is open? By listening you open the port. When there's nothing running on that port, the port is closed.

If you want to check from outside, if a port is open, use a port scanner like nmap. If you want to check it from inside, run `netstat -tulpen` to see what is listening on which ports.

When something binds with `0.0.0.0` this is a wildcard. It stands for every possible IPv4 address. Your "wildcard service" is the same thing, just for IPv6.

Comment: I'm using a python script with socket module to check the port availability. It checks only when there's service is running in that port. If it's a service is running, it will return 0 otherwise 1. To satisfy this condition i'm using netcat to start a service, however even though the service is running in the remote host, it's unable to get the status, it gives the error "Can't grab 0.0.0.0:8080 with bind"

Comment: Well, seems like a problem with your script?

Comment: I thought of it at first too, but however i'm using a i'm using one which i found on google, so it's perfectly works find for others. I've mentioned the part where the it does the port checking.